# Kernel Panics on MBP mid-2010 with a Seagate Hybrid Hard Drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, crash, kernel-panic

I have a mid 2010 MBP 15-inch and I recently replaced the Apple manufacturer hard drive with a 1TB Seagate hybrid hard drive and I am running Yosemite. My MBP crashes randomly when I'm playing League of Legend, working on excels or powerpoint, or doing nothing at all. It is frustrating because it happens every 2-3 hours in average. The Kernel Panic log is here. Can anyone see what's wrong?

> Anonymous UUID:       5C55BD68-43B4-27F0-1D9D-B2D4DB767624
>
> Mon May 25 19:31:05 2015
>
> *** Panic Report ***
>   panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f96e3ebdb): "GPU Panic: [] 3 3 7f 0 0 0 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff813089f000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P3/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.10.22/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
>   Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
>   0xffffff811d532e40 : 0xffffff801412bda1 
>   0xffffff811d532ec0 : 0xffffff7f96e3ebdb 
>   0xffffff811d532fa0 : 0xffffff7f94cc2b9f 
>   0xffffff811d533060 : 0xffffff7f94d8c18e 
>   0xffffff811d5330a0 : 0xffffff7f94d8c1fe 
>   0xffffff811d533110 : 0xffffff7f9500b056 
>   0xffffff811d533240 : 0xffffff7f94daf82d 
>   0xffffff811d533260 : 0xffffff7f94cc95f1 
>   0xffffff811d533310 : 0xffffff7f94cc70fc 
>   0xffffff811d533510 : 0xffffff7f94cc8a4b 
>   0xffffff811d5335e0 : 0xffffff7f96371b37 
>   0xffffff811d5336b0 : 0xffffff7f9639d7de 
>   0xffffff811d533740 : 0xffffff7f96385547 
>   0xffffff811d5337a0 : 0xffffff7f96385e53 
>   0xffffff811d5337f0 : 0xffffff7f963861c0 
>   0xffffff811d533860 : 0xffffff7f96386a11 
>   0xffffff811d5338a0 : 0xffffff7f963520f5 
>   0xffffff811d533a20 : 0xffffff7f963833c1 
>   0xffffff811d533ae0 : 0xffffff7f96350c15 
>   0xffffff811d533b30 : 0xffffff8014700216 
>   0xffffff811d533b60 : 0xffffff801470192b 
>   0xffffff811d533bc0 : 0xffffff80146ff0c3 
>   0xffffff811d533d00 : 0xffffff80141e21e7 
>   0xffffff811d533e10 : 0xffffff801413000c 
>   0xffffff811d533e40 : 0xffffff80141149f3 
>   0xffffff811d533e90 : 0xffffff801412531d 
>   0xffffff811d533f10 : 0xffffff80142031ea 
>   0xffffff811d533fb0 : 0xffffff8014235396

```
    Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.10.22)[26F693CB-BFE8-33FA-9D1F-3F66FC016768]@0xffffff7f96e30000->0xffffff7f96e43fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.10.22)[61967104-88AF-3605-82F5-A480A2800A78]@0xffffff7f96e28000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7f94ba9000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[52E715FC-521D-3869-B2EA-5228FA4BEA34]@0xffffff7f94924000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[82EAD591-67E3-39CB-A232-A8095CA30E92]@0xffffff7f94c1b000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[65E3187E-949B-36E9-BA33-1B13ABB0581A]@0xffffff7f96e2b000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f94c72000->0xffffff7f94edbfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[52E715FC-521D-3869-B2EA-5228FA4BEA34]@0xffffff7f94924000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[C0B8A85D-B32A-3F24-B4FC-B62B3BBF9E57]@0xffffff7f94c62000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[82EAD591-67E3-39CB-A232-A8095CA30E92]@0xffffff7f94c1b000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(10.0)[7FE40648-F15F-3E18-91E2-FDDDF4CDA355]@0xffffff7f94ee6000->0xffffff7f9518ffff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f94c72000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[52E715FC-521D-3869-B2EA-5228FA4BEA34]@0xffffff7f94924000
         com.apple.GeForceTesla(10.0)[5D1B0BFD-2642-35FD-AD39-C0652DA082E8]@0xffffff7f9633e000->0xffffff7f9640bfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[52E715FC-521D-3869-B2EA-5228FA4BEA34]@0xffffff7f94924000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[C0B8A85D-B32A-3F24-B4FC-B62B3BBF9E57]@0xffffff7f94c62000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[82EAD591-67E3-39CB-A232-A8095CA30E92]@0xffffff7f94c1b000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f94c72000

>BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

>Mac OS version:
14D136

>Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 4B3A11F4-77AA-3D27-A22D-81A1BC5B504D
Kernel slide:     0x0000000013e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8014000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8013f00000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)
```

> System uptime in nanoseconds: 69755832219411

```
last loaded kext at 10649900158230: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.3.3b1 (addr 0xffffff7f96f80000, size 20480)
last unloaded kext at 10717800265038: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC  4.3.3b1 (addr 0xffffff7f96f80000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.5
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.18
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   10.0.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.GeForceTesla  10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.10.22
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.11
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.5
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.22
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.10.22
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.4f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.4f4
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.20.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B0F, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.66 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.58f17
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 512 MB
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334348302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334348302D4346382020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.4f4 15601, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: ST1000LM014-1EJ164, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: Do you have any I/O messages in the console?

Comment: It is having Graphics problems.

Comment: As @Buscar웃SD said, this is well known GPU problem in mid-2010 MBP 15 inch. I suffered the same. Unfortunatelly Apple Replacement program has ended and probably the only solution is to replace the whole logic board (quite expensive). [Apple program has ended](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203554).